# display last 10 months based on a specific date

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a cakephp code. in that i store a specific date from database into a var $endate. I store the value of $endate in another variable.
Ex:$date = $endate;
The below loop displays repeated months

```
for ($l = 0; $l < 10; $l++) {
     $month[] = date("Y-M", strtotime($date . " -$l months"));
}
```

output:

```
[0] => 2017-Mar
[1] => 2017-Mar
[2] => 2017-Jan
[3] => 2016-Dec
[4] => 2016-Dec
[5] => 2016-Oct
[6] => 2016-Oct
[7] => 2016-Aug
[8] => 2016-Jul
[9] => 2016-Jul
```

How do i display the last 10 months based on my fetched date?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ah, didn't see that your sequence/output not was correct :-) Deleted part of answer.

I'd recommend using Cake's `Date` class but that doesn't seem to be directly relevant to your question.

Example using Cake's Time class:

```
$now = new \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime();
$monthsToGoBack = 10;
$months = [];

for ($i = 0; $i <= $monthsToGoBack; $i++) {
    $months[] = $now->subMonths($i)->firstOfMonth()->hour(0)->minute(0)->second(0);
}
```

Output: https://gist.github.com/Spriz/a21e6771f71cef0ad659e356737996a0